# Images not displaying on view

Tags: laravel

I am failing to locate where I am missing something. My application is uploading some files into the server. However, when I retrieve the files (images), all the links are broken and I am failing to pick up where the error is.

`index()` method to send the services to the view:

```php
public function index()
{
    $services = Service::all();

    foreach($services as $service) {
        $service->feature_image = Storage::url($service->feature_image);
    }

    return view('services.index')->with([
        'services' => $services,
    ]);
}
```

`store` method:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'feature_image' => 'required|file|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg',
        'description' => 'required|string|min:30|max:150',
        'merchant_id' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if( $validate->fails() ){
        return response($validate->errors(), 400);
    }

    //image storing before
    try {
        $image = $request->feature_image;
        $extension = $image->extension();

        if (! in_array($extension, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])) {
            throw new Exception('File format not supported');
        }

        $imageName = time().'_'.rand(1000, 9999).'.'.$extension;

        $imageName = $request->file('feature_image')->storeAs(
            'feature_images',
            $imageName,
            'local'
        );

        $service = new Service();
        $service->name = $request->title;
        $service->feature_image = $imageName;
        $service->short_description = $request->description;
        $service->merchant_id = $request->merchant_id;

        $service->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }

    $services = Service::where('merchant_id', '=', $request->merchant_id )
        ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'services' => $services,
    ], 200);
}
```

View that's not displaying the images:

```html
<td>
    <img src="{{$service->feature_image}}" style="max-width:300px !important; max-height:100px !important; border-radius:none !important;" />
</td>
```

`filesystems` configuration:

```php
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
    'visibility' => 'private',
],
```

```php
'permissions' => [
    'file' => [
        'public' => 0644,
        'private' => 0600,
    ],
    'dir' => [
        'public' => 0755,
        'private' => 0700,
    ],
],
```

Images are uploading perfectly but just won't display

[image: The images are uploading perfectly]

But, nothing showing on the view

[image]

In the database, image is stored as `feature_images/1675377529_1402.png` and on the frontend, application is trying to load `https://my_domain/storage/feature_images/1675377529_1402.png`

---

#### UPDATE

When I change the disk am writing to `public`, the images show

```php
$imageName = $request->file('feature_image')
    ->storeAs(
        'feature_images',
        $imageName,
        'public'
    );
```

Comment: are the files publicly accessible?

Comment: The suggested way to handle storing images locally and displaying them is via `symlink` between `storage/public/app` and `public/storage`, via the `php artisan storage:link` command: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk. Check those docs and/or run that command, and if there's still an issue, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75329828/edit) with more details, like file permissions, etc.

Comment: Images are only accessed by logged in users who are able to change them.

Comment: I ran php artisan storage:link command.

Comment: Nice, then it's probably an issue with `src="{{$service->feature_image}}"`. Notice how in the docs it's using `asset('storage/...');`? I suspect you need to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks Tim, let me give it a try.

Comment: No luck as yet after adding asset()... Am noticing that the images have permission of  0600 / rwx-xxx-xxx, could this be an issue?

Comment: @Charles play arround with the link and see if you can access the image, then share what link did work for you

Comment: You need to use a public disk. The idea behind a disk with private visibility is only to store and manipulate internally, not to expose the files.

Comment: Thanks @IGP. So what scenarios or examples would you need to use a private disk?

Comment: So, changing my disk to public did id. Was worried about privacy but @IGP clarified it above. 

$imageName = $request->file('feature_image')
    ->storeAs(
        'feature_images',
        $imageName,
        'public'
    );

Comment: I haven't had to use them as much, but for example, say you're storing photos of your client's id card. Nobody should access those. If your client wants to access his own, you should validate it's him in the backend and then you could generate a stream download from that file stored in a private disk.

Comment: Thank you @IGP. Will look more into it as well as it should come in handy.